# Plot colour of 3D point based actual value of each data point

Tags: python-3.x, plot, scatter-plot

I have a 3D array of slopes, X.
I would like to plot each data point and color-code the point based on the actual value. There are three possible values.

if the slope greater 80 then plot data point in red. If the slope greater -80 then blue, else green.

I would also like the legend.
Thanks

I have tried to create a couple of things but not getting it right.

```
#Make the array to 2D with X, Y, Z axis
X=fits.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(-1,3)
print(X.shape)


kcolors = ['red' if slope greater 0.2  elif slope greater -0.2 'green'  else 'blue' for slope in X]

plt.scatter(transformed[:,0], transformed[:,1], transformed[:,2], c=kcolors)


File "<ipython-input-26-4efc22ca2a34>", line 6
kcolors = ['red' if slope > 0.2  elif slope > -0.2 'green'  else 'blue' for slope in points]
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
colors = []
for slope in Xpoints[0]:
    if slope > 0.2:
        colors.append('r')
    elif slope < -0.2:
        colors.append('g') 
    else:
        colors.append('b')
```

This seems to work. 
Is there a better way of doing it?